# How do I apply a mesh to two armature bones

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I've downloaded a rigged armature character from mixamo with the animation that I had in mind. Now, I am trying to attach to this animation movement a spear. This spear I can attach it to the hand bone by doing ctrl+p > bone. However, I need to attach it to the other hand as well, as the character is using his both hands to attack with the spear, but when I try to attach it to the other bone, it stops the connection with the previous bone. Apparently I can only have it attached to one hand bone. How can I attach it to both hands?

Comment: You can use constraints to influence an object with multiple other objects or bones.

Comment: Could you elaborate that please? I've been using blender for 1 week, im still learning

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Is the character you have already setup to be holding a spear? What I mean by that is are the hands posed already and/or are the hands a fixed distance apart in the animation as they would be when holding a spear?